# Parse Section names from ini in PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing, ini

I've been messing with this code all night long, and haven't been able to get it quite right, and am unsure of what to even search for.

Here's what I'm doing.  I am using PHP to parse .ini files to an HTML table.

Here is what I am using in the html file:

```
<?php
  $datas  = parse_ini_string(file_get_contents( 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12345/test.ini' ), true);
?>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tbody>
    <?php
      foreach( $datas as $data ) {
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $data["name"] ); ?></td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Points</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $data["Name"] ); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $data["Points"] ); ?></td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I would like to show up on the table is what is notated as "Section n" Below:

```
[Section 1]
Points=3

[Section 2]
Points=173

[Section 3]
Points=173
```

I am unclear on how to show "Section n" in the table, I would like it to take the following format:

```
Section number  |  Points
Section 1       |  3
Section 2       |  173
Section 3       |  173
```

Any help or pointers is greatly appreciated!  Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is code that works, you can use the key to get the section name.

```
<?php
  $datas  = parse_ini_string(file_get_contents( 'http://hastebin.com/raw/ikovafilib' ), true);
?>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tbody>
    <?php
      foreach( $datas as $section => $data ) {
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $data["name"] ); ?></td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Points</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $section ); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $data["Points"] ); ?></td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT: In future, when you're dealing with an array that you don't know the output of, you can use print_r() function to debug what it outputs.

Comment: Pure wonderful magic!  Thank you so much for your help, that worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

Ini `parse_ini_file` section name is added as key.

Try using

```
<?php
  foreach( $datas as $key => $data ) {
?>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $key ); ?></td>
  <td>Points</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $key ); ?></td>
  <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $data["Points"] ); ?></td>
  </td>
</tr>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: This worked!  as $key => $data..man I would have had no worldly idea!  THanks so much!!!